# Problem with a variable in a Laravel Project

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with a variable in my Laravel project.

I put a SQL request in a variable and when I do a dd() I have in my variable that I want :

Request :

```
$sumDepenseGroupByDate = DB::select('select sum(depense_somme) "somme",depense_date from depense GROUP BY depense_date order by depense_date');
    dd($sumDepenseGroupByDate);
```

Output dd():

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#282 ▼
    +"somme": "850"
    +"depense_date": "2020-12-22"
  }
  1 => {#281 ▼
    +"somme": "200"
    +"depense_date": "2020-12-23"
  }
  2 => {#280 ▼
    +"somme": "400"
    +"depense_date": "2020-12-24"
  }
]
```

After I send my variable in the blade and when I want to use this variable in JS, the values were changed. The "somme"($row->somme) is good but the "depense_date"($row->depense_date) is wrong

console.log() :

```
var data_date = []
@if ($resultat!="")
  @foreach ($sommeDepenseGroupByDate as $row)
    console.log({{$row->depense_date}});
    data_date.push({{$row->depense_date}})
    data_somme_add_tab.push(sommeAAjouter + {{$row->somme}});
    sommeAAjouter += {{$row->somme}};
  @endforeach
@endif
console.log(data_date);
```

Output console.log() :

````
```
1986
1985
1984
(3) [1986, 1985, 1984]
```
````

I don't understand why values are different between the dd() and the console.log()

Thank's for your feedback and sorry for my english, i have done my best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing single quotes around your values. Check the difference between these two `console.log()` statements.

```
console.log(2020-12-22) # 1986 (2020 minus 12 minus 22, the dashes are treated as minuses)
console.log('2020-12-22') # '2020-12-22' (String representation of the date)
```

When you transfer PHP variables to JS, you need to make sure they don't get parsed as something else. In your case, since you're expecting dates, make sure they treated as dates and not mathematical expressions. So, in your code, simply do:

```
console.log('{{ $row->depense_date }}');
```

There might be "safer" approaches, like `json_decode()`, etc etc, but the main issue is that you're not treating your strings as strings.

Edit: `somme` is ok, cause addition relies on numeric inputs, and `{{ $row->somme }}` is outputting `850`, `200`, etc. just fine.